# Cumulative distinct count of multiple fields in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct

I have a property database and I am currently designing a query for additional characteristics of the properties. In this case the two tables in question are those:

This is the first Characteristics table which is basically where I store the meta for each characteristic.

[image: Characteristics table]

This is the CharacteristicsPerProperty database where I store the relation and final value of the specific characteristic.

[image: CharacteristicsPerProperty Table]

So basically what I want to do is count all the unique `id_propiedad` (`property_id`) so that I can show how many I have available with that specific characteristic. The query is the following

```sql
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CaracteristicasPorPropiedad.id_propiedad)) AS disponibles
FROM
    CaracteristicasPorPropiedad
WHERE
    CaracteristicasPorPropiedad.id_caracteristica = 1
    AND
    CaracteristicasPorPropiedad.valor = 3
```

So basically the output is something like:

```
| disponibles |
|=============|
| 264         |
```

Everything works as expected up to here, but I can also include another parameter, let's say in the previous example I included Recámaras (Bedrooms), but I also want to include Baños (Bathrooms). I tried

```sql
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CaracteristicasPorPropiedad.id_propiedad))
FROM
    CaracteristicasPorPropiedad
WHERE
    (CaracteristicasPorPropiedad.id_caracteristica = 1 AND CaracteristicasPorPropiedad.valor = 3)
    AND
    (CaracteristicasPorPropiedad.id_caracteristica = 2 AND CaracteristicasPorPropiedad.valor = 2.5)
```

The thing is that this query returns 0.

If I switch the AND to an OR it returns 282 results. I basically need the combination of both. I am a little stuck with this. What could be a query to mix multiple levels of this? It can be used with all 10 available dimensions for this characteristic.

Comment: Tag our question with the database you are using.

Comment: Done. I added the mysql tag.

Comment: `CaracteristicasPorPropiedad.id_caracteristica = 1 AND CaracteristicasPorPropiedad.id_caracteristica = 2`.  How could this be ever true???  It will always return false, thus it will not return any row, thus `count()` will always be 0.

Comment: @Eric I know that, any recommendations on how to do the count with both conditions?

Comment: What's your logic?  What do you want to get?

Comment: What happen if you change the `AND` between brackets to `OR` ie (id_caracteristica = 1 and valor = 3) or (id_characteristica = 2 and valor = 2.5)?

Comment: As it says in the question "If I switch the AND to an OR it returns 282 results. I basically need the combination of both. I am a little stuck with this. What could be a query to mix multiple levels of this? It can be used with all 10 available dimensions for this characteristic." It basically returns more than before instead of reducing.

Comment: @Eric I want to get the count of properties that have both `id_caracteristica = 1` and `id_caracteristica = 2` and so on. It's for count badges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `id_propiedad` using aggregation:

```
SELECT cpd.id_propiedad
FROM CaracteristicasPorPropiedad cpd
WHERE (cpd.id_caracteristica = 1 AND cpd.valor = 3) OR
      (cpd.id_caracteristica = 2 AND cpd.valor = 2.5)
GROUP BY cpd.id_propiedad
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cpd.id_caracteristica) = 2;
```

If you want the count, use a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT cpd.id_propiedad
      FROM CaracteristicasPorPropiedad cpd
      WHERE (cpd.id_caracteristica = 1 AND cpd.valor = 3) OR
            (cpd.id_caracteristica = 2 AND cpd.valor = 2.5)
      GROUP BY cpd.id_propiedad
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cpd.id_caracteristica) = 2
     ) p;
```

Comment: But in this case I want the condition in which the property would coincide with both criteria, not one or the other, that's my problem. The query I mentioned above, used with `OR` instead of `AND` gives me the same number your second query gives, but it should reduce the number instead of increasing it. With one condition the table returns 264 results and with two conditions 282.

Comment: @MihailMinkov . . . This returns only `id_propiedad` that  have both conditions.

Comment: I am not sure I follow, in this case if I use Condition A OR Condition B it means that it would count properties with either A or B as parameters, not necessarily both. That means that if I count Condition A AND Condition B it would count properties that have both Condition A and Condition B which is what I require. That's what I want to achieve.

Comment: @MihailMinkov . . . That is because it does not make sense without the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Woah, one learns something new everyday. Thanks Gordon! Just to clarify, I'd have to update the `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cpd.id_caracteristica) = 2` with the number of characteristics I require right?